# ¿Qué significa el símbolo de exclamación en la condición en función If en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy empezando a usar Js en mis primeros proyectos. Ahora estoy haciendo un menú burguer que cambie de forma cuando hacemos click en el sitio web. Buscando, encontré el siguiente código, pero no entiendo qué significa el símbolo de exclamación antes de la primera condición `!menuOpen`. ¿Me podrían ayudar a entender qué significa en este caso?

```
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu_btn');
let menuOpen = false;
menuBtn.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    if (!menuOpen) {
        menuBtn.classList.add("open");
        menuOpen = true;
    }
    else{
        menuBtn.classList.remove("open");
        menuOpen = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: estás negando dicha función... En este caso, tenemos `si menuOpen no es  verdadero` o `if(menuOpen != true)`. Su significado sería el IS NOT.

Answer (score 3):

Es prácticamente una evaluación `booleana`:

```
if(menuOpen == false){}  es igual a if(!menuOpen){} 

if(menuOpen == true){}   es igual a if(menuOpen){}
```

Answer (score 2):

Significa que estás negando el menuOpen, es decir si menuOpen es igual a falso  en la condición se evalúa a verdadero. En lógica formal es el equivalente a "¬".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT

Comment: Si el valor de menuOpen _puede convertirse a falso_* (a tener en cuenta los valores _truthy_ y _falsy_).

Answer (score 1):

El operador lógico `!` devuelve `true` o verdadero cuando la expresión a la izquierda da como resultado `false` o falso, o invierte el comportamiento del `if` dicho de otra forma.

Por ejemplo, si yo quiero que se active el `if` cuando mi variable `myvar` de tipo boleana es `false`, simplemente escribiría:

```
if(!myvar) //...
```

también se puede para comprobar que lo que está dentro de un paréntesis da `false`, por ejemplo:

```
if(!(myvar == "Hola Mundo" && myvar2))
```

En el ejemplo puedes ver que el `if` será `true` cuando myvar no sea igual a `"Hola Mundo"` y `myvar2` no sea `true`